# C# WPF oledb MS Access

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, oledb

I have:
1) C# WPF DataGrid
2) MS Access db that include one table ("Temp")!
   I already read a lot of forums and arcticles but I'm not find an answer! 
I want to add/edit/delete data in MS Access DB using DataGrid!
I'm tried these code but it's doesnt work!

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dataSet != null && _dataSet.Tables[0] != null && _dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified))
        {
            DataTable dt = _dataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            adapter.Update(dt);
        }
        adapter.Update(_dataSet.Tables["Temp"]);
    }
```

I'm from Ukraine so translalte u!
I have an error (I'm hope I do it right):
"Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported for the SelectCommand, does not return any key column information"
Error like this always return when use update or ad data to DataGrid!
PLEASE, Help me!
Thanks You for a all!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will use ORM (object relational mapping) for data access. For .NET exist: Entity Framework, Fluent Nhibernate, Dapper (micro-orm) - maybe beast options for you because it is very simple. Also note MVVM pattern (beast option for WPF). Good article with example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! I look it and wirte my opinion about MVV soon!

Answer (score 0):

A have an answer! 
To work this code he need a key cell(column)!
If there is not, commandBuilder can't get a default comands, so you always get an errors! Here are code:
`adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comand, con);
            _dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(_dataSet, "TargetAndProbability");
            cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            cb.QuotePrefix = "[";// it's need if your cells contains others symbols
            cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";`

Than all very simple!

```
adapter.Update(_dataSet, "TargetAndProbability");
```